# Function to check option list validation not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select option list for my form and I want to make sure the user has selected one of the options. My function logic implies that if the user keeps the dropdown on the default option, an alert will pop up prompting them to change it. However, no alert shows up whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function isOption(form) {
  var type = form.getElementByID("pastimetype")
  var selectedValue = type.options[type.selectedIndex].value;
  if (selectedValue == "selectpastime") {
    alert("Please select a pastime.")
    return false
  }
  return true
}
```

```html
<p><label for="pastime"> Favourite pastime: </label>
  <select name="pastime" select id="pastimetype">
    <option value="selectpastime">---Please choose an option---</option>
    <option value="surfingtheweb">Surfing the Web</option>
    <option value="playingsport">Playing Sport</option>
    <option value="listeningtomusic">Listening to Music</option>
    <option value="watchingtv">Watching TV</option>
    <option value="playinggames">Playing Games</option>
    <option value="communityservice">Community Service</option>
    <option value="daydreaming">Daydreaming</option>
    <option value="reading">Reading</option>
    <option value="meditation">Meditation</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: Where is `isOption` called?

Comment: I made you a snippet. You need to call the isOption

Comment: You never call `isOption` and you made a typo, the function is called `getElementById`.

Comment: what if NONE are selected, how do you handle that?

Comment: If NONE are selected, thats when I want the alert to show up. No selection would mean the option '---Please choose an option---' would be left as is by default

Answer (score 0):

- you need to add the function to the submit event of the form.
- you misspelled getElementById
- no need to use form.getElementById
- easier to get the value using select.value
- use preventDefault instead of returning true/false

Also

```js
function isOption(e) {
  var sel = document.getElementById("pastimetype");
  var selectedValue = sel.value;
  if (selectedValue == "") { // I removed the value from the "Please select"
    alert("Please select a pastime.")
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.getElementById("form1").addEventListener("submit",isOption)
})
```

```html
<form id="form1">
<p><label for="pastime"> Favourite pastime: </label>
  <select name="pastime" select id="pastimetype">
    <option value="">---Please choose an option---</option>
    <option value="surfingtheweb">Surfing the Web</option>
    <option value="playingsport">Playing Sport</option>
    <option value="listeningtomusic">Listening to Music</option>
    <option value="watchingtv">Watching TV</option>
    <option value="playinggames">Playing Games</option>
    <option value="communityservice">Community Service</option>
    <option value="daydreaming">Daydreaming</option>
    <option value="reading">Reading</option>
    <option value="meditation">Meditation</option>
  </select>
</p>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```